# What is the right way to import 3rd party React components into the kotlin.js project?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop, kotlin-frontend, create-react-kotlin-app

I'm trying to use this lib in my [create-react-kotlin-app](https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app):

https://material-ui-next.com/

I want to generate bunch of type safe wrappers. I started like this:

```
@file:JsModule("material-ui")

package material

import react.RState
import react.React
import react.ReactElement

external class Typography : React.Component<dynamic, RState> {
    override fun render(): ReactElement
}
```

...

```
fun RBuilder.typography(
    classes: String = "",
    variant: Variant = Variant.body1,
    align: Align = Align.inherit,
    color: Color = Color.default,
    gutterBottom: Boolean = false,
    noWrap: Boolean = false,
    paragraph: Boolean = false,
    handler: RHandler<dynamic>
) = child(Typography::class) {
    attrs {
        this.className = classes
        this.align = align.name
        this.color = color.name
        this.variant = variant.name
        this.gutterBottom = gutterBottom
        this.noWrap = noWrap
        this.paragraph = paragraph
    }
    handler()
}
```

And use it like:

```
typography(variant = Variant.title, color = Color.inherit) {
    +"Hello World"
}
```

Is it correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed that is the correct way but can make it to be the best as follows

MaterialUi.kt

```
@file:JsModule("material-ui")

package material

import react.RState
import react.RProps
import react.React
import react.ReactElement

external interface TypographyProps : RProps {
    var className: String
    var align : String
    var color : String
    var variant : String
    var gutterBottom : String
    var noWrap : String
    var paragraph : String
}

@JsName("Typography")
external class Typography : RComponent<TypographyProps, RState> {
    override fun render(): ReactElement
}
```

And then create another file, say

MaterialUiDsl.kt

```
fun RBuilder.typography(
    classes: String = "",
    variant: Variant = Variant.body1,
    align: Align = Align.inherit,
    color: Color = Color.default,
    gutterBottom: Boolean = false,
    noWrap: Boolean = false,
    paragraph: Boolean = false,
    handler: RHandler<TypographyProps> // notice the change here
) = child(Typography::class) {
    attrs {
        this.className = classes
        this.align = align.name
        this.color = color.name
        this.variant = variant.name
        this.gutterBottom = gutterBottom
        this.noWrap = noWrap
        this.paragraph = paragraph
    }
    handler()
}
```

If the above file already seems verbose to you (Like how I often feel), you can change it to just

MaterialUiDsl.kt

```
fun RBuilder.typography(handler: RHandler<dynamic>) = child(Typography::class,handler)
```

The you can use it whenever like this

```
typography {
    attr {
        className = "my-typo"
        color = "#ff00ff"
        //. . .
    }
}
```

Easy peasy

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in adding a ReactJS 3rd party component to Kotlin code. Please take a look at the following post, I'd appreciate any feedback regarding the solutions proposed there:

[How to import node module in React-Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431848/how-to-import-node-module-in-react-kotlin)