# How to use node module in Kotlin React?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, npm, create-react-kotlin-app

I'm trying to use the bootstrap library. To do so, my first guess was to do the same as the Kotlin React tutorial :
I managed to import the bootstrap library using npm import easily but then I struggle to actually use it and in particular to add arguments. As shown in the example:

```
@file:JsModule("react-bootstrap")
@file:JsNonModule

 import react.*

@JsName("Button")
external val ReactButton: ComponentClass<ReactButtonProps>

external interface ReactButtonProps : Props {
   var variant: String
   var size: String
}
```

Which indeed creates a button when used :

```
ReactButton {
  variant="primary"
  size = "lg"
  +"Exemple"
}
```

But the color and size aren't changing whatever argument I put.
Then I tried to proceed like another topic on Stack Overflow: [How to import node module in React-Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431848/how-to-import-node-module-in-react-kotlin)
But I don't understand what RProps are and RClass and I can't seem to use them.
My goal is to use a dropdown from Bootstrap but I thought trying with button first would have been easier. How do I make the button customizable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your head tag in your index.html folder

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />`

make sure you have `implementation(npm("react-bootstrap","2.4.0"))`  in your build.gradle.kts within your js dependencies

Comment: Thank you ! it worked ! But as a beginner I don't exactly see why ... I don't exactly understand what this code does :/

Comment: Glad I could help :D and we all gotta start somewhere, right ?
Bootstrap and react-bootstrap are 2 different things. In order for react-bootstrap to work you need to install bootstrap either through npm or cdn according to their official page [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start]
Simply, react-bootstrap is like a set of React components built using Bootstrap (for styling), for example you can use a ready-made nav-bar, button etc..

Comment: Ok i get it now ! Thank you so much !